# What are ECN fees?  Are ECN fees under an investor's control?  

Tags: stocks, trading, fees, commission

At this Questrade link: http://www.questrade.com/trading/stocks_ecn_101.aspx

... they explain what kind of trades incur ECN fees. At this moment, I do not understand a lot about these fees. But so far as it seems, they are pretty much out of my hand... i.e. I cannot do anything to control them.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fee for the automated processing of your order through the Electronic Communication Network (ECN).  Since you as an individual buyer (or seller) must go through the market to load up / unload your securities, no, you can't do anything about the fees.  Other brokerages might give you better deals, but the ECN fees are part of their costs, so they'll pass them on to you somehow.